# do I require a potentiometer

Tags: raspbian

I am trying out online tutorial to practice python and raspberry pi. 
I am currently following this tutorial:
http://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/wiring

It says a potentiometer is needed, but i dont have one...
what will happen if i connect without a potentiometer.
will it destroy my pi or will it not work?

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to wait for shipping (without a pot, contrast will be off, and the display will not be readable at all)

If you have some different value resistors, you can try some different combinations of 2 resistors, to form a voltage divider (a pot is basically a variable voltage divider). Try to find a combination where the contrast of the display is good enough to read.

To make the process of guessing a bit easier you can create a pot by drawing a thick line with some pencil (http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-Pencils-Lead-Potentiometer-Experimentatio/). Connect ground to one end, and 3.3v to the other. Add a lead to the contrast pin and move it around the line, till the contrast is good. Next take you multimeter and measure the voltage at that point. Then calculate a resistor combination that will produce that voltage.

Answer (score 1):

It won't destroy your Pi, as can be seen in the tutorial the Potentiometer is simply for contrast. QUOTE:

> Next, wire up the **contrast potentiometer**...

So, the Potentiometer isn't for safety, it is to make the LCD usable/readable!

Basically, if you want to use this tutorial, you have to have a potentiometer, otherwise the LCD will be out of contrast, and thus useless.

Potentiometers are usually pretty cheap and you can get several for a good price, as you can see here. [This Potentiometer](http://www.adafruit.com/products/356) is the one they use in the tutorial, and is only $1.25, while [this one](http://www.adafruit.com/products/562) is a little less pretty and is only $0.95. Both should work fine and both are from Adafruit (supplier for that tutorial).